# python pickle UnicodeDecodeError 'latin1' not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, gzip, pickle

I'm trying to do some neural network work, but I got file coded with for Python 2.7, and I have Python 3.6 . That is my code :

```
import _pickle as cPickle
import gzip
import numpy as np
def load_data():
    k = gzip.open('../data/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(k, encoding='latin1')
    k.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)
```

And that is the error I keep getting :

> File "mnist_loader.py", line 44, in load_data
>       training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(k, encoding='latin1')
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 614: ordinal not in range(128)

Looking through StackOverflow, I saw people saying that I should put 'encode = 'latin1'', so that's what I did but I keep having the problem.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I tried this :

```
with gzip.open('../data/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb') as k:
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = cPickle.load(k, encoding='latin1')
    k.close()
return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)
```

And it appears to be working, but I have no idea why ;)

Thanks everyone !